# Dynamically form generation vs adding new class

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

There are two ways to create a form in c# application:

> 1. Add a new class describing form elements and behavior
> 2. Generate it all dynamically.

Q : What are the advantages of the second method?
    Which can give more performance or reduce memory using and how about scalability?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8293404/design-vb-net-ui-dynamically-or-at-compile-time

Comment: check your spelling....dynamically...describing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static UI should be your first choice. Dynamic UI is an option to consider, but only if you have a compelling reason. If you don't have a concrete reason to look for dynamic UI, and just have a vague feeling that one might be better then the other, then stick to static UI.